# Finding text in 100 pages

Tags: html, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I was asked this in a recent interview:

*Imagine you have a website with 100 pages listing various products a company offers. The company decides to change a particular name of product from "A" to "B". Someone has obliged and changed the names, and now the company wants to make sure that all the replacements have been made. 
What will you do to check if all the replacements have indeed been made?*

( No tags were mentioned, nothing else)

Possible Answers:

1.

> I thought it would be easier to just open the site and use a search
>   bar to iterate over all the pages manually. Or maybe calling all the
>   p, h1, h2, h3, etc elements and iterating over them. But i'm sure
>   there is a better way.

2.

```
 //A possible solution
 if(driver.getPageSource().contains("your Text"))
{
    //What should the code be here?
}

else
{
    //Click abc
}
```

Comment: If the web site was well built the product name would be being driven by data, not simply hard coded into 100 html pages.

Answer (score 1):

Imagine you were an employee for this company:

I think you should talk to the developers first, the developers will tell you which web element' attribute(s) represent a product that is on sale.

If you use brute force to search for a string "**product A**", you might get a false positive:

- what if **product A** has been replaced **product B**, but on their web site, they state: ***product A has been discontinued and replaced by product B***. Then your test will fail but it is merely a false positive.

Answer (score 0):

You could try (example in C#):

```
bool containsProductName = driver.PageSource.Contains("product name here");
```

To quickly check a page for the text you're looking for, the best way to loop through all 100 pages is largely going to depend on the structure of the site.